# Resolving conflict between android:gravity and android:layout_gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Consider the following trivial layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The **outer** `LinearLayout` specifies that it has

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

which means that it wants its children to "fall to the bottom".

The **inner** `LinearLayout` specifies that

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```

which means that it wants *itself* to be laid out at the top of its enclosing layout. (To specify `android:layout_gravity` one must apparently edit the XML file directly. There does not seem to be a way to reach that attribute from Eclipse. Anyhow...)

How does Android resolve such a conflict? The example above suggests that the `gravity` attribute overrides the `layout_gravity` attribute. Is that how the conflict is resolved in general?

Answer (score 1):

From taking a look at the `layoutVertical()` method in [`LinearLayout`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java), **the `gravity` of the `LinearLayout` itself is what determines how the children are positioned**.

The `layout_gravity` of each child is used only for laying out "in the other direction" (i.e. left-right).

First:

```
    final int majorGravity = mGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    final int minorGravity = mGravity & Gravity.RELATIVE_HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;

    switch (majorGravity) {
       case Gravity.BOTTOM:
           childTop = ... 
           break;

       // ... same for CENTER_VERTICAL and TOP
    }
```

Then, for each child:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getVirtualChildAt(i);

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int gravity = lp.gravity;
        if (gravity < 0) {
            gravity = minorGravity;
        }

        final int layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
        final int absoluteGravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity, layoutDirection);
        switch (absoluteGravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
            case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
                childLeft = ...
                break;

            // ... same for RIGHT and LEFT
```

And equivalently for `layoutHorizontal()`.

Also, just a comment but `android:layout_gravity` *can* be accessed from Java code. It's the [`gravity` field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity) in the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` class (which is set as the `LayoutParams` of the child view).